# How do I use Alamofire's RequestAdapter to set firebase ID token as a global header?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

After I authenticate a user with firebase, I am getting the ID Token because my REST service is using the firebase token for authentication.

On the ios side, I want to store this token so that every request I make will have the Authorization header set with the token.

Alamofire doc suggests to use RequestAdapter https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#requestadapter

So I make a TokenInterceptor:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

final class TokenInterceptor: Alamofire.RequestInterceptor {
    private var token: String
    
    init(token: String) {
        self.token = token
    }
    
    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest

        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + self.token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        completion(.success(urlRequest))
    }
}
```

Then I want to use it but I don't understand how to use this with `AF` or `Session`.  Here is my state class:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import Alamofire

class AuthenticationState: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var error: NSError?
    @Published var loading: Bool = true
    
    private let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    private var fbUser: FirebaseAuth.User?
    
    func signInWithEmailPassword(email: String, password: String) {
        self.auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handleAuthResultCompletion)
    }
    
    private func handleAuthResultCompletion(auth: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.loading = false
            if let fbUser = auth?.user {
                self.fbUser = fbUser
                fbUser.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true) { idToken, error in
                  if let error = error {
                    // Handle error
                  }
                
                    // What am I to do here?  How does this affect AF namespace? 
                    Session(interceptor: RequestInterceptor(token: idToken ?? ""))
                    
                    self.me()
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                self.error = error as NSError
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func me() {
        AF.request("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/me").response { response in
            print(response)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RequestAdapter` on a per-`Session` or per-`Request` basis. `Session`'s initializer can take the value, which is then used for all requests:

```swift
let session = Session(interceptor: Interceptor(adapter: YourAdapter()))
```

Or you can set it on a request:

```swift
AF.request(..., interceptor: Interceptor(adapter: YourAdapter()).response ...
```

You can read more in our [`Session` documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adding-a-requestinterceptor) or [`Request` documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adding-a-requestinterceptor).

Comment: Thank you Jon.  I followed your advice, and set this custom session as a private variable on my AuthenticationState class above.  Then I added a `authenticatedRequest()` to which I can pass the URL Convertible params and it will use the private session.  Since I am useing it as a environment object, any of my views will be able to use the authenticatedRequest.  Is this what you mean when you say it is recommended to use this custom session?  Thanks, I am still learning so please also let me know if I said any terms wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend separate `Session`s for unauthenticated vs. authenticated calls. Instead, you can use the per-`Request` APIs to only attach the adapter to the requests that need to be authenticated. There are a lot of approaches here, including your convenience method, or using our `URLRequestConvertible` protocol to build everything for a request.

Comment: Thanks!  that makes sense